# Sendgrid Peronalizations Array Limit along with the total number of recipients

Tags: python, sendgrid

Sendgrid Personalization -> I have read the official documentation of Sendgrid Web_API_v3 . On Personalization topic I have read that we have the limit of 1000 personalizations instances creation per request.But could not find the limit quota of recipients (TO + CC + BCC ). As in the same documentation of I have read that we can send 1000 recipients (TO + CC + BCC) at a time.
Please Confirm the personalization  objects limit along with the recipients quota because   I have not read these two statement consolidated at same page.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-mail-send-faq/

> There are rate limits on how frequently you can call the v3 Mail Send endpoint. Currently, you may make up to 10,000 requests per second to our endpoint. Each email you send may include up to 1000 recipients. For more information on other limitations, and how this may impact your integration, please visit our